# How to collect user input without using Strings in Java

Tags: java

This is supposed to be a rock paper scissor game, there's more to the code after, but I don't have to change anything on it.

I'm a little confused on how to use the Scanner to collect user input without using Strings. The comments are the instructions that I'm supposed to follow to finish the code/ some of my comments to point out the problem area.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RPSGame {
    // 1 is Rock
    // 2 is Paper
    // 3 is Scissors
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startMessage ="****************************START*******************************\n";
        String endMessage = "\n****************************END*******************************\n";
        System.out.println(startMessage);
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        //**************************** DO NOT MODIFY ANYTHING BEFORE THIS LINE*****************************
        // To-Do: Add print statement to welcome User to the game
  System.out.println("Welcome to the RPS game! Are you ready?");
        // To-Do: Add print statement prompting User to enter 1, 2, or 3 (explain which each number represents)
  System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 3. 1 is for Rock, 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissors ");
        // To-Do: Use scnr.nextInt() to collect user input, save it as an int variable called choice
        int java.util.scnr.nextInt choice;  //I'm stuck on this part of the line, how am I supposed //to use to collect user input without using Strings?(that was part of the requirement for the //assignment?) I'm still pretty new to this and idk what to put/change for this line.
      
        // To-Do: Complete the following line using Math.Random() to generate a int
        // In the range 1-3
        int computerChoice = ((int)(Math.random())*3); //Idk if I did this part right
```

Comment: `// To-Do: Use scnr.nextInt() to collect user input` - that comment seems pretty explanatory, what do you not understand about it?

Comment: `int java.util.scnr.nextInt choice` should be `int choice = scnr.nextInt()` (this is exactly what the comment says to do) not really sure why you are trying to put `nextInt` as the type

Comment: `int java.util.scnr.nextInt choice;` doesn't look right. Lets start with basics. We can *declare* variables via `type variableName;`. We can *initialize/assign* value to variables via `variableName = value;`. We can do both of those things at once via `type variableName = value;`. The `value` part can be provided in code like `int = 123;`, or copied from other variable like `int n = otherVariable;` or result of some method like `int n = tree.getHeight();`. In your case you want to use *result* of calling `nextInt()` method on `scnr` object, which means `int choice = scnr.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.scnr.nextInt` is not a type.
`scnr` is not a package in Java.

It seems likely that you want to use something like:

```
int choice = scnr.nextInt();
```

which is an invocation of the `nextInt` method call.